# Dynamic Range with Formula Array VBA

Tags: vba, dynamic, excel-formula

I have a question about Formula Array in VBA. I trying to run a formula on a range of cells and the range I am picking my data from is changing in a loop. I get the error that "FormulaArray doesn't function with Range class". I have tried to divide the formula into parts but with no luck. I am guessing that it has something to do with how I reference Cells? It works well when the formula uses the `R1C1` style but not when I'm using `Cells`. Note that the code is working from another sheet than the actual sheet `ws2`

```
   Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
       Dim ws2 As Worksheet
       Dim y_out As Range
       Dim y_in As Range
       Dim x_in As Range
       Dim x_out As Range
       Dim length As Long

       Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
       For i = 1 To datasets

                length = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, i + 4).End(xlUp).Row

                Set y_out = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(2, i * 4 + 2), ws2.Cells(length, i * 4 + 2))
                Set y_in = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(2, i * 4 + 4), ws2.Cells(length, i * 4 + 4))
                Set x_in = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(2, i * 4 + 3), ws2.Cells(length, i * 4 + 3))
                Set x_out = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(2, i * 4 + 1), ws2.Cells(length, i * 4 + 1))

                y_out.FormulaArray = "=loess(x_in,y_in,x_out,50)"

                FormulaArray = "=loess(RC[1]:R[490]C[1],RC[2]:R[490]C[2],RC[-1]:R[490]C[-1],50)"


       Next i

    End Sub
```

Comment: Do your `y_in` and `y_out` overlap - that would cause a circular reference.  You have a spurious `FormulaArray = _` line doing nothing that should be commented out or deleted.  The `FormulaArray` property only accepts functions in English formatting (there is no `FormulaArrayLocal` to match `FormulaLocal`) so you should use commas instead of semicolons to split up your arguments, and the English names intead of the local ones.  (What is `loess`?)

Comment: There are no issues with `y_in` and `y_out`. Those variables are correct and refers to their respective column. I have my Excel set to Swedish but `FormulaArray` still works when using `R1C1` notation. But I need to be able to change the columns where `y_out` picks up my data. My previuos code was a bit misleading since I my `x` and `y` variables didn't change with the loop. `loess` is a function to smooth the `y_in` data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I could actually solve it using the `R1C1` notation and with fewer lines of code. Since the `R1C1` notation works relative to the active cell I just needed a way to add the variable `length` to the formula using `" & length & "`. It works because `y_out`changes location after every iteration.

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

   Dim ws2 As Worksheet
   Dim y_out As Range
   Dim y_in As Range
   Dim x_in As Range
   Dim x_out As Range
   Dim length As Long

   Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
   For i = 1 To datasets

            length = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, i + 4).End(xlUp).Row

            Set y_out = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(2, i * 4 + 2), ws2.Cells(length, i * 4 + 2))


            y_out.FormulaArray = "=loess(RC[1]:R[" & length & "]C[1],RC[2]:R[" & length & "]C[2],RC[-1]:R[" & length & "]C[-1],50)"


   Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`x_in`, `y_in`, etc are not Named Ranges, but you are attempting to use them as though they are.

This gives 2 solutions:  Makes them Named Ranged (and change it accordingly) or use their `.Address`:

```
y_out.FormulaArray = "=loess(" & x_in.Address & ", " & y_in.Address & ", " & x_out.Address & " , 50)"
```

Comment: I didn't see your answer before I posted mine but I think you are probably right. Your answer was actually what I was looking for. As I mentioned I'm not that familiar how to work with the different notations.Thank you!

Comment: @Mattias The `.Address` function actually has an argument called `ReferenceStyle` which can be `xlA1` or `xlR1C1` (default is `xlA1`) - but, for this, it doesn't really matter which it outputs.